# Date/Time Conversion from YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Tags: apex, datetime

I have a Date/Time value from a JSON response in the form of 2020-10-01T15:22:20 that I am trying to convert to something that looks like 10-01-20 15:22 in Apex. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you can use the apex [DateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) class:

```java
// replace the 'T' with blank space to make date time string compatible with format method
String dtString = '2020-10-01T15:22:20'.replace('T', ' ');

// Convert the string to DateTime
DateTime dt = DateTime.valueOfGMT(dtString);

// Now use formatGMT method with appropriate dateFormatString to convert DateTime to string 
String dtNewString = dt.formatGMT('MM-dd-yy HH:mm');

System.debug(dtNewString);
```

In the console this outputs as:

> DEBUG|10-01-20 15:22

Comment: That worked, thank you Raul!